# How to set chip select in SPI programming for multipleslaves ? (struct spi_ioc_transfer)

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, spi

Maybe I am asking the wrong question actually but I am just making my first steps in the embedded world. So I am sorry if the question is somehow stupid.

I am trying to program a software for 9DOF IMU in c++ and linux environment.

As far as I understood the SPI, the SS pin has to be low active in order for a transmission to occur. I have seen multiple reading or writing bytes function examples and all using the struct spi_ioc_transfer but they were all single slave examples and there is no mention about setting or configuring the SS in the code. Also When I check the structre of spi_ioc_transfer there is the cs_change however, how does it know which cs we are dealing with from the beginning ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chip select (CS or SS) to use is determined by which device node you open.

To talk to a SPI chip with the Linux spidev driver, you open a device such as /dev/spidev0.1. The numbers in the device node file name refer to the bus and chip select, respectively — in this example it would be the first bus (0) and the second CS (1). If you want to talk to devices on different chip-selects, you have to open different device nodes and do ioctls on the appropriate one.

Comment: Thank you that cleared a lot ! If it is okay for you, I would like to ask another question. I understand now what you mean. I did not really see a lot of exmples with mutiple SPI nodes (lets say 3) so my question here is how I associate each SPI node to the regarding CS to it ? so when I communicate using the ioctl, i am sure I am using the right fd then for that node. I also do not really need to put the ss low manually in code right ? have not seen it done. Thanks again for your help

Comment: @Hesham.K the available chip-selects are defined in the device tree (on ARM systems), that gets sent to the Linux kernel by the firmware at boot time. And no, you don't have to manage CS manually in code, the kernel driver takes care of that.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Much appreciated !

Comment: While it's proper answer, the problem with the original code is that SPI slave should have a driver in the kernel. And for sensors it's usually IIO with a corresponding helper in user space `libiio`. https://wiki.analog.com/resources/tools-software/linux-software/libiio